# Adding methods to converter class with an interface

Tags: c#, interface, converters

I have written an fairly simple convert class, which turns `Foo` into `Bar`.

Because I want multiple converters for other classes, I have set up an interface with two methods:

```
public interface IConverter<in TSource, out TDestination>
{
    TDestination Convert(TSource sourceObject);
    IEnumerable<TDestination> ConvertMany(IEnumerable<TSource> sourceObjects);
}
```

And my class implements this like so:

```
public class ObjectConverter : IConverter<Foo, Bar>
{
    public Bar Convert(Foo sourceObject)
    {
        return new Bar
        {
            // Mapping attributes...
        };
    }
    public IEnumerable<Bar> ConvertMany(IEnumerable<Foo> sourceObjects)
    {
        return sourceObjects.Select(obj => new Bar
            {
                // Mapping attributes...
            });
    }        
}
```

Which all works wonderful. I wanted to add another `ConvertMany` method which takes another objects as source and returns it as `Bar`. Would it be fine to add it to this class since it also returns `Bar` or is this something that would be more fitting for a second class which also implements this interface?

I'm fairly new to C# and using interfaces, so I'm unsure what would be better.

(On a side note, does any of this make sense? Are there better alternatives?)

Comment: Do you just want to add one other method or at least both of the implemented methods for your other source object?

Comment: Both would work, but I'd only need `ConvertMany`.

Comment: so you should use it like: `ObjectConverter : IConverter<Foo, Bar>, IConverter<Baz, Bar>`

Comment: You might want to read the docs on the built-in [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can inherit from for your own classes.

Comment: @Jamiec I'll definitely go through that, but it's basically just to improve readability a bit. Doesn't feel like complicated code is needed.

Comment: Its not complicated, you implement one method which tells it how to convert from one type to another - much like your code does.

Comment: Oh thought it was more complicated, I'll try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another implementation of your interface to achieve the expected results:

```
public interface IConvertFromMany<TSource, TDestination>
{
    IEnumerable<TDestination> ConvertMany(IEnumerable<TSource> sourceObjects);
}

public interface IConverter<TSource, TDestination> : IConvertFromMany<TSource, TDestination>
{
    TDestination Convert(TSource sourceObject);

}
```

Use it like:

```
public class ObjectConverter : IConverter<Foo, Bar>, IConvertFromMany<AnotherSourceObject, Bar>
{
   //....your implementations here        
}
```

Comment: I can see how that makes sense, but what if I only wanted to have the `ConvertMany` method, would it be considered bad if I'd just add it to that class?